# Overriding Angular Datepicker UI > Angular2

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

I want a calendar in my webapp, but I don't want it to look like the standard Angular UI, or even a bootstrap UI. I want to dictate the look and feel myself.

It seems like it was easy to change the UI in Angular 1 by changing the template html (see [Can you override specific templates in AngularUI Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap/17677437#17677437)), but I can't understand how to do the same post Angular 2.

I'm working with an Angular Cli dev environment, just using the Angular Material datepicker from https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

How do I change how it looks?

Ultimately, I might want to just grab information from the datepicker, rather than displaying it - so I might want to know how many days there are in a given February, or whether September starts on a Tuesday? How would I do that?

Comment: RTFM is  a good start ... https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: Too basic for what I want I'm afraid - I want to create arrays of HTML elements in a table to make a calendar.

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550969/how-to-overwrite-angular-material2-styles and https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/747. Look at the end of the second link.

Comment: Hmmm - what I want to do is not just style - I want to design a whole new GUI for the data. I was really hoping to just access whatever data is behind the calendar and build my own template around it, but I'm starting to feel I might have more luck with a REST API just feeding me json data